# How can an Indian national get a Jamaica tourist visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, jamaica

I'm from India.I want to travel Jamaica.

Can anybody tell me all the formalities?

Answer (score 0):

Jamaica is visa free for Indian visitors. Which means that you do not need a visa to travel there. However, according to their [department of immigration](http://www.pica.gov.jm/immigration/general-immigration-information/travel-documents-required-for-all-other-travellers/), you need the following documents with you when you travel.

1. a valid passport or other acceptable travel document
2. a valid visa or authority to enter Jamaica (including work permit,
   student permit, temporary permit)
3. a completed and signed Immigration Landing Card
4. Anyone who arrives without a valid travel document, visa or
   authority to enter Jamaica, may be refused entry to Jamaica or
   delayed until their identity and claims to enter Jamaica have been
   confirmed.

However, depending on which route you take (it's unlikely you will find any direct flights to Jamaica from India) you will need to find out whether you will need transit visas in advance for the stopovers. Most likely you will need this.